# phonegap external storage

Tags: mysql, database, cordova, websocket

I am using phonegap to make iphone and android apps. I need to be able to store data on a mysql database on my server as well as use my websocket server.

How can I go about doing this as the app will be running on local html and javascript files which cant run ajax/websocket requests on external servers?

Comment: Why can't you send ajax requests to the backend, again?

Comment: If I am using phonegap with local javascript files, how can i send an ajax request to a php script that other iphone/android users can all access?

Comment: By using a backend server in the cloud somewhere, and making other devices poll this device.

Comment: How would I poll a backend server with javascript?

Comment: Again, ajax calls. Your device sends updates to the database in the backend using ajax and it gets stored there. The other devices keep polling the backend (again, ajax) to get the updates. Someone has to run the house in the back.

Comment: Agreed with @SudiptaChatterjee, I have several apps on multiple platforms that all happily interrogate the same database on my remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let me convert my comments into an answer.

You need a client-server architecture, where the clients will be all your end devices. The server in this case needs to be a globally reachable host somewhere (Amazon cloud, perhaps?).

Your device will send updates to the backend server that has a connection to your database, using **ajax** calls. These updates will be stored on the server.

All your other clients need to periodically poll the same backend server using **ajax**, and will get the updates sent from your primary device.

Comment: Provide an example script and ill believe it. I'm wondering how you're thinking you'll get around same origin policy